# vb.net How to get this inner text from webbrowser

Tags: vb.net

i m trying to get some information from webbrowser control to textbox. i tried this;

```
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("Table")
```

or tried this;

```
WebBrowser1.Document.All("table")
```

but i cant fin a sollution. my html cose like this;

```
<form id="formArea" method="post">

<table id="infoTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
        <tbody><tr>
          <td class="td_sol">information 1</td>
          <td class="td_sag">information 2</td>
          <td class="td_sol">information 3</td>
          <td class="td_sag">information 4: 123456</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="td_sol">bla bla</td>
          <td class="td_sag">bla bla</td>
          <td class="td_sol">bla bla</td>
          <td class="td_sag">bla bla</td>          
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="td_sol">bla bla</td>
          <td class="td_sag">bla bla</td>
          <td class="td_sol">bla bla</td>
          <td class="td_sag">bla bla</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="td_sol">bla bla</td>
          <td class="td_sag">bla bla</td>
          <td class="td_sol">bla bla</td>
          <td class="td_sag">bla bla</td>
        </tr>


</tbody></table>
</form>
```

i need to get "information 4: 123456"'s only "123456" to textbox.

i have second choice for get this number. İn html another tags(8 pieces) got this number like this;

```
<input type="hidden" name="ImpCustomer.customerNum" value="123456">
```

or like this(14 pieces);

```
<input type="hidden" name="hCustomerNumber" value="123456">
```

Can anyone find a way to get this information? And maybe anyone know how can i find a tag's number in a table then a can get this to textbox?

Pls help me.
My regards.

Answer (score 1):

You could get the HTML document as a string, using [WebBrowser.DocumentText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documenttext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Then use [String.IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof.aspx) to find `<td class="td_sag">information 4:`. Finally simply use [String.Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to extract the value.

Comment: Thx for help. How can i get the HTML document as string?

Comment: Simply use `.DocumentText` instead of `.Document`

Comment: i tried but i cant :( can you give me a example code?

Comment: @user3449489 _What_ did you try? What did the computer say? Do you have any ideas? Do you have any other information that might be helpful?